# QML virtual keyboard dimensions

Tags: android, qt, keyboard, qml, qt5

I'm having trouble finding the dimensions for the virtual keyboard. Here's an example:

```
Rectangle {
    Component.onCompleted: {
        Qt.inputMethod.visibleChanged.connect(resizeForKeyboard)
    }

    Component.onDestruction: {
        Qt.inputMethod.visibleChanged.disconnect(resizeForKeyboard)
    }

    function resizeForKeyboard(){
        console.log('Visibility changed!!!');
        var keys = Object.keys(Qt.inputMethod.keyboardRectangle);
        var rect = Qt.inputMethod.keyboardRectangle;
        //A simple script I have for debugging, this loops 
        //through the keys and prints all properties
        DataMethods.printObject(keys, '[INPUT]');
        DataMethods.printObject(rect , '[RECTANGLE]');
    }

    //using the controls to save time
    TextField {
      focus: true //force keyboard to show up.
    }
}
```

**datamethods.js (relevant method)**

```
/**
 * This method prints an object to the console for debug purposes
 * obj -> the objec to print
 * prefix -> the prefix to append "[prefix] -> "...
 * props -> a list of properties to use, otherwiese all will be printed
 */
function printObject(obj, prefix, props) {
    if(!prefix)
        prefix = "obj";

    if(obj){
        console.log(prefix + obj + "->" + typeof obj);
        if(props){
            for(var p in obj)
                console.log('\t' + prefix + "["+ p + "] -> '" + obj[p] + "'");
        } else {
            for(var p in obj)
                console.log('\t' + prefix + "["+ p + "] -> '" + obj[p] + "'");
        }
    } else {
        console.log(prefix + "is null");
    }
}
```

**Here's the output:**

```
[INPUT]objectName,cursorRectangle,keyboardRectangle,visible,animating,locale,inputDirection,destroyed,destroyed,objectNameChanged,deleteLater,_q_reregisterTimers,cursorRectangleChanged,keyboardRectangleChanged,visibleChanged,animatingChanged,localeChanged,inputDirectionChanged,show,hide,update,reset,commit,invokeAction->object
D/Qt      (30122): qrc:js/datamethods.js:153 (printObject):     [INPUT][0] -> 'objectName'
D/Qt      (30122): qrc:js/datamethods.js:153 (printObject):     [INPUT][1] -> 'cursorRectangle'
D/Qt      (30122): qrc:js/datamethods.js:153 (printObject):     [INPUT][2] -> 'keyboardRectangle'
D/Qt      (30122): qrc:js/datamethods.js:153 (printObject):     [INPUT][3] -> 'visible'
D/Qt      (30122): qrc:js/datamethods.js:153 (printObject):     [INPUT][4] -> 'animating'
D/Qt      (30122): qrc:js/datamethods.js:153 (printObject):     [INPUT][5] -> 'locale'
D/Qt      (30122): qrc:js/datamethods.js:153 (printObject):     [INPUT][6] -> 'inputDirection'
D/Qt      (30122): qrc:js/datamethods.js:153 (printObject):     [INPUT][7] -> 'destroyed'
D/Qt      (30122): qrc:js/datamethods.js:153 (printObject):     [INPUT][8] -> 'destroyed'
D/Qt      (30122): qrc:js/datamethods.js:153 (printObject):     [INPUT][9] -> 'objectNameChanged'
D/Qt      (30122): qrc:js/datamethods.js:153 (printObject):     [INPUT][10] -> 'deleteLater'
D/Qt      (30122): qrc:js/datamethods.js:153 (printObject):     [INPUT][11] -> '_q_reregisterTimers'
D/Qt      (30122): qrc:js/datamethods.js:153 (printObject):     [INPUT][12] -> 'cursorRectangleChanged'
D/Qt      (30122): qrc:js/datamethods.js:153 (printObject):     [INPUT][13] -> 'keyboardRectangleChanged'
D/Qt      (30122): qrc:js/datamethods.js:153 (printObject):     [INPUT][14] -> 'visibleChanged'
D/Qt      (30122): qrc:js/datamethods.js:153 (printObject):     [INPUT][15] -> 'animatingChanged'
D/Qt      (30122): qrc:js/datamethods.js:153 (printObject):     [INPUT][16] -> 'localeChanged'
D/Qt      (30122): qrc:js/datamethods.js:153 (printObject):     [INPUT][17] -> 'inputDirectionChanged'
D/Qt      (30122): qrc:js/datamethods.js:153 (printObject):     [INPUT][18] -> 'show'
D/Qt      (30122): qrc:js/datamethods.js:153 (printObject):     [INPUT][19] -> 'hide'
D/Qt      (30122): qrc:js/datamethods.js:153 (printObject):     [INPUT][20] -> 'update'
D/Qt      (30122): qrc:js/datamethods.js:153 (printObject):     [INPUT][21] -> 'reset'
D/Qt      (30122): qrc:js/datamethods.js:153 (printObject):     [INPUT][22] -> 'commit'
D/Qt      (30122): qrc:js/datamethods.js:153 (printObject):     [INPUT][23] -> 'invokeAction'
D/Qt      (30122): qrc:js/datamethods.js:147 (printObject): [RECTANGLE]QRectF(0, 0, 0, 0)->object
```

I might be going about this the totally wrong way and I would love a way to handle it. The reason I need the size of the keyboard on the device is so I can respond in my UI and not bury controls below it (so the user can continue to scroll through the form).

As you can see the `keyboardRectangle` property of Qt.inputMethod appears to be default values.

Where should I be retrieving this information, the signal seems correct as it fires on open/close of the virtual keyboard?

Comment: hiya i just wondered if you have had any luck with this as I'm also struggling with this problem. thanks

Comment: None at all! This problem exists in 5.2.0 and I have not tested 5.2.1 but it is probably time to file a bug report.

Comment: wow that sucks lol. and your probably not going to be happy to hear that I am running 5.3 beta alpha/beta (I'v forgotten) and its still the same. I'm almost resorting to making my own keyboard which I really don't want to do.

Comment: By the way I saw from some of your answers that you've been learning qt for am while now. So I just wanted to ask a couple of qu's.I have put quite a few questions up which I researched for quite some time and didn't find anything and I would class them as very standard stuff that other people want to do in android and other os's, but I didn't really get any answers which I'm a little surprised at. So I was just wondering if you'd be able to take a look at some of them and see if you think you might be able to help with any of them.I'm sure they'll help quite a few people if they were answered

Comment: I'll try to take a look. I've basically bypassed the roadblocks I've hit.

Comment: Have everyone got luck?

Comment: Appears that the `inputMethod()` resources does not have been implemented completely.
I got a way to retrieve the keyboard dimensions, but using a little bit of Java, and I'm not sure if you are looking only for a Qt way to get these informations or not.

Comment: Please! This is a major bug in the Kit right now. Android supports custom keyboards so a workaround is the only option.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to get the virtual keyboard dimensions by using `QDesktopWidget::availableGeometry();` to get the usable screen size, `QDesktopWidget::screenGeometry();` to get the fullscreen dimensions and a little bit of Java code to get the menubar size.

And here are the most relevant parts of the code:

C++ side:

```
QRect KeyboardInterface::rect()
{
    int menuheight = (int)QAndroidJniObject::callStaticMethod<jint>("org.qtproject.example.Demo2.JavaInterface", "getHeight");

    QDesktopWidget widget;
    QRect rect = widget.availableGeometry();
    QRect geom = widget.screenGeometry();

    rect.moveTop(rect.top() + menuheight);
    geom.setTop(geom.top() + menuheight);

    QRect final;

    if (rect != geom)
    {
        int ftop, fleft, fwidth, fheight;

        geom.getRect(&fleft, &ftop, &fwidth, &fheight);

        if (rect.top() != ftop)
            fheight = rect.top();
        else if (rect.left() != fleft)
            fwidth = rect.left();
        else if (rect.height() != fheight)
            ftop = rect.height();
        else if (rect.width() != fwidth)
            fleft = rect.width();

        final = QRect(fleft, ftop, fwidth - fleft, fheight - ftop);
    }

    return final;
}
```

Java side:

```
package org.qtproject.example.Demo2;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;

public class JavaInterface extends org.qtproject.qt5.android.bindings.QtActivity
{
    private static JavaInterface instance;

    public JavaInterface()
    {
        instance = this;
    }

    public static int getHeight()
    {
        Rect r = new Rect();
        Window window = instance.getWindow();
        View rootview = window.getDecorView();
        rootview.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(r);

        return r.top;
    }
}
```

A full source code of this project can be found [here](https://github.com/antonypro/QtKeyboardRect)

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

For all Qt versions below 5.6, this is an intended behavior of Qt on Android. The reason stated was that soft keyboards on Android are not restricted to be shown on the bottom of the screen as it's the case for iOS: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-40731

**For Qt 5.6 and above the bug is fixed and the keyboardRectangle returns a valid rect on Android too.**

Comment: Later the referenced bug [got fixed for real](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-40731#comment-520289), so this answer no longer applies in general, but *only* in the rare case where a user configured a floating Android keyboard.

Comment: Downvoting to indicate that this answer is no longer applicable. Normally I never downvote, but I want to mark it somehow to save others some confusion about the current state. You might want to edit or delete the answer.

Comment: @tanius thanks for the feedback, I updated the answer to only reference the issue on Qt 5.6 and below.

Comment: Thank you, that makes it clear! Removed the downvote now.

Answer (score 0):

The erroneous "`Qt.inputMethod.keyboardRectangle` is always 0 x 0" behaviour seen by the OP was [a bug in Qt](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-40731) that **has been fixed** on 2015-12-07, with the fix being released in Qt 5.7.

Since then, `Qt.inputMethod.keyboardRectangle` will contain the correct size, except in the rare case of a floating Android keyboard. It does not happen under iOS, where the keyboard is restricted to the bottom of the screen. This limitation is now also [documented](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qinputmethod.html#keyboardRectangle-prop) in the official Qt documentation:

> **QInputMethod::keyboardRectangle:** Virtual keyboard's geometry in window coordinates.
>
> This might be an empty rectangle if it is not possible to know the geometry of the keyboard. This is the case for a floating keyboard on android.